# Mongoose - Find documents that contain a reference of sub-documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 models,

```
var locationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
});

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String
});
```

I would like to get all Location that has a specific user. For example, with following data,

```
Location      Users
    A         [1,2,3]
    B         [1,4,5]
    C         [6]
```

Say, I want to find all locations that has user #1. I've tried following, didn't work

```
var locationModel = mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);

locationModel.find({
    users : { $in: user }
});

locationModel.find({
    'users._id' : user._id
});

locationModel.find({
    'users.$oid' : user._id
});

locationModel.find({
    'users.id' : user._id
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
locationModel.find({
    users : { $in: [some_user_id] }
});
```

Comment: Would seem right, but unfortunately this guy is using Mongoose models for this, so it is not embedded. See the **first** schema definition. The documents are in another collection.

Comment: @zPhiNGpHoNG This may work with an `_id` but you *might* want to look into [embedded documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) if it is going to suit your use case. If you can do that then querying *related* information from your User Schema is going to be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, Neil. But if I do embedded document, it'll make duplicated data. I prefer not to.